# Clone ScatterViewItem control in Surface Application

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I'm working on a Windows multitouch application using Surface 2.0 SDK.
I need to "clone" a control, in this specific case a ScatterViewItem, in which I've added a ElementMenu with a "CopyButton" with a Click event handler.
This is my ScatterViewItem:

```
<s:ScatterViewItem x:Name="PhotoPadSVI"  MinWidth="296" Background="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource ScatterViewItemStyle}">......</ScatterViewItem>
```

And this is the code that I used and that doesn't work:

```
void DocumentDuplicate_Click(object sender,  RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
    ScatterViewItem swi = PhotoPadSVI; //error is already here cause I set it as the same, but I cannot found a ".Clone()" like method
    swi.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    swi.ZIndex = 100;
    swi.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Bottom;

    //sView.Items.Add(swi); cannot add to ScatterView cause swi is equal to PhotoPadSVI
}
```

**Question**: Do you know in which way could I replicate the ScatterViewItem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a *new* instance of `ScatterViewItem`. It should work if you set its `Content` the same as `PhotoPadSVI's`.

```
ScatterViewItem swi = new ScatterViewItem() { Content = PhotoPadSVI.Content };
```

If there is still error indicating you can't add the same item to `ScatterView`, you have to do from scratch, create the new `ScatterViewItem's` `Content` from code, this can be a lot more complicated if `PhotoPadSVI's` `Content` is a bunch of XAML code.

Also refer to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dssurface/archive/2010/02/24/how-to-create-a-self-replicating-scatterviewitem.aspx).